# Best suitable approach to find nearest neighbour to (x, y, z) from list of triplets

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to obtain a triplet from list of triplets that is closest to my required triplet incase if it was not found.

For example:

```
           # V_s,V_g,V_r 
triplets = [(500, 12, 5), 
           (400, 15, 2.5), 
           (400, 15, 3),
           (450, 12, 3),
           ... ,
           (350, 14, 3)]
```

The triple that I am looking for is

```
req_triplet = (450, 15, 2)    #(Vreq_s, Vreq_g, Vreq_r)
```

How can I achieve this in python, a best suitable strategy to achieve is what I am in need for.

As of now I am thinking to filter the list by finding nearest parameter V_s. From the resulting list filter further by finding nearest to V_g and finally by V_r.

Comment: How are you defining "nearness"?

Comment: I am not defining any nearness, the thing is my req_triplet either should be found from list or atleast check one that is nearest based on dictonary alphabet sort type

Comment: If you aren't going to define what you mean by "nearest" then your question is not well-defined.

Answer (score 2):

You can compute **Euclidean distance** with `numPy` or you can use
[`numpy.linalg.norm`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html).

Try this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> def dist(x,y):   
...    return np.sqrt(np.sum((x-y)**2))

>>> triplets = [(500, 12, 5), (400, 15, 2.5), (400, 15, 3),(450, 12, 3)(350, 14, 3)]
>>> req_triplet = (450, 15, 2)

>>> arr_dst = [np.linalg.norm(np.array(tr) - np.array(req_triplet)) for tr in triplets]
>>> arr_dst = [dist(np.array(tr), np.array(req_triplet)) for tr in triplets]
>>> arr_dst
[50.17967716117751, 50.002499937503124, 50.00999900019995, 3.1622776601683795, 100.00999950005]

>>> idx = np.argmin(arr_dst)
>>> idx
3

>>> triplets[idx]
(450, 12, 3)
```

Comment: It is an euclidean distance for 3 space system right?

Comment: thank you, it can be potential solution for my situation

Comment: @pptOUT in this approach, `((x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) + (z1 - z2))^2` then compute `sqrt of the sum`.

Comment: @pptOUT welcome, you can use `abs` or `sqrt((a-b)^2)` but with pow^2 you can zoom on the small number in your problem you can choice you need `abs` or `sqrt((a-b)^2)`

Comment: Understood, will decide based on my results :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a metric ||.||, then the triplet T that is close to a fixed one F is the one that minimize ||T - F||. You can use a classic Euclidean distance:

```py
import numpy as np
def dist(u, v):   
    return np.sqrt(np.sum((np.array(u)-np.array(v))**2))
```

Comment: Yup thinking if it is the only solution for my case, Thank your Mr.Madrisan

Comment: Maybe you need a different metric that is more suitable for your use case.

Comment: Yeah, I am confused but eventually will figure it out based on if I yield good results. The solution you suggested is mathematical one but something is better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The general strategy would be to Loop through the list, for each element calculate the distance and check if it is the minimum, otherwise keep going on.

In python this would look something like this-

```
from math import abs
triplets = [(500, 12, 5), 
           (400, 15, 2.5), 
           (400, 15, 3),
           (450, 12, 3),
           ... ,
           (350, 14, 3)]
req_triplet = (450, 15, 2)
def calc_dist(a,b):
    return sum((abs(a[i]-b[i]) for i in range(3))
def find_closest_triple(req_triplet,triplets):
    min_ind = None
    min_dist = -1
    for i,triplet in enumerate(triplets):
        if e == req_triplet:
            return i
        dist = calc_dist(req_triplet,triplet)
        if dist < min_dist:
            min_ind = i
    return min_ind
```

Comment: As I can see, we are summing up the absolutes in calc_dist function. Is it not possible some sort of normalization like  (V_s/V_g, V_r)? Will it still results in a valid neighbour?

Comment: Your definition of a valid neighbour depends on your definition of the distance, I think at that point it is more of a maths question and not a  programming one.